# WCF-service with xsd generated dataclasses returns empty objects

Tags: wcf, xsd, wscf

I have an xsd-file with which I generate dataclasses (with xsd.exe or WSCF-blue) for building a WCF-service.

Then I add the generated classes to the operations in the WCF-service like this:

```
MyGeneratedClassOUT operation1(MyGeneratedClassIN request)
```

When I call that operation from a client, the client gets back `MyGeneratedClassOut` request filled with null-values, even tough i fill them up server-side.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? 
Could this be a problem in the XSD-file or in the WCF configuration?

Comment: check the wire response in Fiddler or WCF logging - does it contain values or nulls? also compare the namespace between the response and request to see if client and server are in sync

Comment: It was a namespace problem. The ServiceContract and the datamembers had a different namespace!

Comment: great - I would appreciate if you can mark my suggestion as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably a namespace issue. Check with Fiddler if the request and response have the same namespaces.